# How can I exit console app exe uninterrupted. (The application terminates before the ProcessExit method completes)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, windows-task-scheduler, taskkill

I have a .net 5.0 console application. I scheduled that application exe in task scheduler.
Sometimes, when I end the task, the application kills without finishing the parts I have coded to finish. (I am stopping some services, and writing things in a file if the application exiting. It needs a little bit of time.)

I tried the following command but not working. It is doing the same things.

```
taskkill /t /f /im "ApplicationEXEName.exe"
```

I am looking for a way to do wait to finish my actions if application exiting.

I had tried setting ShutdownTimeout when the application host creating like this. But it also not working.

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigConfiguration)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<HostOptions>(opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                ConfigureDefaultServices(services);
                ConfigureServices(configuration, services);                 
            })
            .UseSerilog(Log.Logger, true)
            .Build();
```

Comment: A console mode app is too simplistic to support this.  You should create a service instead, OnStop() is available to shutdown cleanly.  If you still need the scheduler to activate it then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416835/windows-service-in-task-scheduler-service-cannot-be-started-the-service-proce).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so apparently you can do something like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += ProcessExitHandler ;
    }

    static void ProcessExitHandler( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("You can't shut me down. I quit!" ) ;
    }
}
```

in which case, if your application is closing, firstly this ProcessExitHandler will be called. I have never tried it though. If it works the way it is intended you might be able to pull of anything you like before the application closes.

[Detect when console is being closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117906/detect-when-console-is-being-closed)

if that doesn't help I would check these:

[Why does closing a console that was started with AllocConsole cause my whole application to exit? Can I change this behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959643/why-does-closing-a-console-that-was-started-with-allocconsole-cause-my-whole-app)

[Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp)

Comment: Already I have ProcessExitHandler method. I put a breakpoint at that method and attached the process. It comes on breakpoint when I end the process on task scheduler (or taskkill command) but visual studio debug mode closing automatically in 1-2 second. Also I do not see a log on event viewer about visual studio closing.